# Getting the wrong association with ifelse function

Tags: r

I have a big data.frame and need to create a column with a categorical variable "Season" of Column "Month".

```
structure(list(year = c("2017", "2017", "2017", "2017", "2017", 
"2017", "2017", "2017", "2017", "2017", "2017", "2017", "2017", 
"2017", "2017", "2017", "2017", "2017", "2017", "2017", "2017", 
"2017", "2017", "2017", "2017", "2017", "2017", "2017", "2017", 
"2017", "2017", "2017", "2017", "2017", "2017", "2017", "2017", 
"2017", "2017", "2017", "2017", "2017", "2017", "2017", "2017", 
"2017", "2017", "2017", "2017", "2017"), month = c(1, 2, 2, 1, 
1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 1, 3, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 5, 8, 1, 1, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 2, 3, 
3, 4, 4, 1), day = c("29", "12", "12", "25", "25", "01", "01", 
"29", "29", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "14", "31", "02", "28", 
"25", "31", "21", "18", "12", "01", "01", "28", "07", "18", "16", 
"30", "26", "24", "22", "12", "16", "13", "10", "10", "11", "01", 
"28", "29", "04", "01", "01", "28", "28", "29", "29", "10")), row.names = c(NA, 
-50L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I used the ifelse function like bellow:

```
a <- c(3,4,5)
b <- c(6,7,8)
c <- c(9,10,11)
d <- c(12,1,2)

df$season <- ifelse(df$month == a, "Spring",
               ifelse(df$month == b, "Summer",
                      ifelse(df$month == c, "Fall",
                             ifelse(df$month == d, "Winter",
                           ""))))
```

But I am getting the wrong association in the column Season. Many values that should have a season name is " ".

I also tried:

```
df[df$month == a, ][, "Season"] <- "Spring"
df[df$month == b, ][, "Season"] <- "Summer"
df[df$month == c, ][, "Season"] <- "Fall"
df[df$month == d, ][, "Season"] <- "Winter"
```

But it did not work.

Comment: Use `%in%` instead of `==`

Answer (score 4):

Here, the issue is that each of the `vector` elements are of `length` > 1.  For this, we can use `%in%`

```
df$season <- ifelse(df$month %in% a, "Spring",
           ifelse(df$month %in% b, "Summer",
                  ifelse(df$month %in% c, "Fall",
                         ifelse(df$month %in% d, "Winter",
                       ""))))
```

---

Also, in `tidyverse`, we can do

```
df %>%
     mutate(season = case_when(month %in% a ~ "Spring",
                               month %in% b ~ "Summer",
                               month %in% c ~ "Fall",
                               month %in% dd ~ "Winter",
                               TRUE ~ NA_character_))
```

---

If there are many values, a much better approach would be join after creating a key/val datasset

```
library(tidyverse)
map2_df(lst(a, b, c, d), c("Spring", "Summer", "Fall", "Winter"),
        ~ tibble(month = .x, val = .y)) %>% 
   right_join(df) %>% 
   select(month = val, year, day)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Great explanation!

Answer (score 2):

You should do:

```
df$season <- ifelse(df$month %in% a, "Spring",
                    ifelse(df$month %in% b, "Summer",
                           ifelse(df$month %in% c, "Fall",
                                  ifelse(df$month %in% d, "Winter",
                                         ""))))
```

Since you are using "==", you are comparing df$month only to the first elements of a, b, c and d.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much!

Comment: Lennyy, I am trying to do the same with a variable that has decimal numbers. But it doesn't work. The class is "numeric", but it is not working. Exemple, I have a class that is a <- c(0:200000) and I have numbers that I want to classify like 169392.96, but r do not recognize as in the "a"vector. Even when I use "%in%". What could be wrong?